# sass-loader get SassError on version 13.0

Tags: webpack, sass, sass-loader

To make rails legacy code to work, I add asset-data-url function to convert icon file to inline. 
It work will until sass-loader version 12.3.0, but not work on version 13.0.

error message

```
SassError: [object Object] must be a Sass value type.
```

This is the sample code.

```js
const defaultSass = require('sass');

module.exports = function sassFunctions() {
  const sass = defaultSass;

  return {
    'asset-data-url($filename)': function (filename) {
      // just return svg or base64 file content
      const imgData = 'url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\' '/%3E %3C/g%3E %3C/svg%3E ")';
      return new sass.types.String(imgData);
    },
  };
};
```

in webpack.config, add custom function to sass-loader -> sassOptions -> functions.

```js
// import custom function
const assetFunctions = require('../sass-asset-functions/index');
{
          test: /\.(scss|css)$/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
              options: {
                esModule: false,
              },
            },
            {
              loader: "css-loader",
              options: {
                // 2 => postcss-loader, sass-loader
                importLoaders: 2
              }
            },
            {
              loader: "postcss-loader",
              options: {
                postcssOptions: {
                  plugins: [
                    ["autoprefixer", { grid: true }],
                  ],
                },
              },
            },
            {
              loader: 'sass-loader',
              options: {
                sourceMap: true,
                sassOptions: {
                  functions: assetFunctions()
                }
              }
            },
          ],
        },
```

Comment: Have you found solution